# How to set a app-wide font in Android?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I am working on an app wherein I need to set a custom font (Lato) to all controls (textview, edittext, spinner, etc). I have installed `Lato.ttf` in `assets` folder. I know how to change the font for each element but I have hundreds of controls in my app and it is not a feasible solution for me.

I am building for Android 4 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project may be helpful : 
https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy

Comment: This is definitely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a BaseActivity and have all your Activities/Fragments extend this class. In your BaseActivity you can set the custom font you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it up manually, iterating over all children of your root ViewGroup, usually in `onCreate()` in `Activity` or `onCreateView()` in `Fragment`

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do this is to create your own class.

For instance for `TextView`, create a class `MyTextView` that extends `TextView`. In each constuctor add a call to a `init` metod :

```
public void init() {
     Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "your_ttf_file");
      setTypeface(typeface);
}
```

Then replace all occurence of TextView in your xml files with your.package.MyTextView

Then all of your `TextView` have the good typeface.